# accessing of nsstring method with nsarray using categories?

Tags: ios, xcode

After creating a method with nsstring type in a category, i am trying to access that method in my view controller as below:

NSArray *ggg=[ggg removeCharactersFromString:stringWithChars];

it is showing error this time. But with the same array if i am using objectAtIndex:0 it is accessing without an error.

```
NSArray *ggg;
[[ggg objectAtIndex:0] removeCharactersFromString:stringWithChars];
```

Why this is happenning? I am unable to diagnoise the problem.

Please any one help me.

Comment: -1 and a vote to close for saying "showing an error" without telling us what it is.

Comment: (And you you really deserve another -1 for not showing us how your category is declared.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For being sure you should place the definition of removeCharactersFromString: stringWithChars method. But I guess that removeCharactersFromString is a method that can be applied to a NSString, instead to a NSArray. If the object At Index 0 is a NSString the method should not show an error.

Comment: I got the logic. When declaring an array that can access only instance methods. But the method removeCharactersFromString: is an class method so that it is happening. Thank You for your response.